# Wordpress - Trailing Slash using .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am creating a plugin to add the trailing slash to all the URLs of the site using .htaccess file.
When I am adding the code to forcefully add the trailing slash, all the pages are redirecting multiple times and throwing an error of ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I know we can add trailing slash using permalinks in wordpress, but want to achieve it through the .htaccess file.

.htaccess file of Default wordpress is having below code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

On the top of above code when I am trying to add below code of for adding trailing slash, I am getting the error of too many redirects.

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|xml|txt|js|php|scss|webp|mp3|avi|wav|mp4|mov|pdf|html|htm|xst)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Error page is shown like below.

[Error Image After adding the code for trailing slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk1TN.png)

I stuck in this since last multiple days and still not able to find the proper solution.
Can someone please help?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: I am guessing this is probably WP itself redirecting back to what it thinks is the "proper" URL, the one _without_ the slash. _"I know we can add trailing slash using permalinks in wordpress, but want to achieve it through the .htaccess file."_ - if you want to work _against_ your system, don't be surprised if that leads to problems. (It doesn't even make much sense, WP will still create the links without the slash in the HTML it outputs, so you would do a redirect for _every_ page/post request then ... decreasing performance.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

This works for me, try this.